# Understanding inheritance when class has ::

Tags: c++

Confused by this class

```
class ParaViewMainWindow::pqInternals : public Ui::pqClientMainWindow
{
public:
  pqInternals()
  {
  }
};
```

What does it mean?

If it's something like `class ParaViewMainWindow: public pqClientMainWindow` I know that `ParaViewMainWindow` inherits from `pqClientMainWindow`, right?

But here it has `::pqInternals` and later

```
pqInternals()
  {
  }
```

What exactly is this doing?

I know `::` is the scope operator and I have use it, but never in this situation.

Comment: In this case, `Ui` is a namespace. So the class `pqClientMainWindow` is a class in the `Ui` namespace. The `ParaViewMainWindow::pqInternals` is likely that `pqInternals` is a subclass of `ParaViewMainWindow`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the definition of the class `ParaViewMainWindow`, it contains the declaration `class pqInternals;` (and most likely a member that is a pointer to `pqInternals`).

This is the definition of that class – its full name is `ParaViewMainWindow::pqInternals` – and it inherits from `Ui::pqClientMainWindow`, which is the class `pqClientMainWindow` in the namespace `Ui`.